# Spring Test mock one dependency

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, spring-test

Suppose I have these two parts of XML Spring config in two distinct files;

```
//daoContext.xml
<bean id="myDao" class="com.MyDao"/>

//logicContext.xml
<bean id="myLogic" class="com.MyLogic">
    <constructor-arg ref="myDao"/><!--or other type of injection--?
</bean>
```

And there is the test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration("logicContext.xml")
public class BaseLogicTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyLogic myLogic;

    @Test
    public void testMyTestable() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is to be able to mock `MyDao` class and inject is somehow into `MyLogic` which is to be injected in `BaseLogicTest` so I can use `MyLogic` with a mocked `MyDao`. Is this possible using Spring/Spring Test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is load all your xml. And manually replace dependence in test case.

```
@ContextConfiguration("logicContext.xml")
public class BaseLogicTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyLogic myLogic;

    @Before
    public void injectTestDoubles() {
        myLogic.setMyDao(...);
    }

    @DirtiesContext
    @Test ...//test methods
}
```

But this corrupts the application context, so you need @DirtiesContext if you need "real" myDao in other test case sharing the same application context.

The most popular solution (my personal opinion :P ) is using mockito and a test-specific xml.

```
//daoContext.xml
<bean id="myDao" class="com.MyDao"/>

//logicContext.xml
<bean id="myLogic" class="com.MyLogic">
    <constructor-arg ref="myDao"/><!--or other type of injection--?
</bean>

//test-logicContext.xml
<bean id="myDao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.MyDao" />
</bean>

@ContextConfiguration({"logicContext.xml", "test-logicContext.xml"})
public class BaseLogicTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyLogic myLogic;

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;//retrieve mock so you could define expectations

    @Test //test methods

    @After public void clearMocks() {
        Mockito.reset(myDao);//this is important if you have several test methods
    }
}
```

And this solution works for other mock framework like easyMock.

Comment: The first solution isn't really feasible since `myDao` contains a `dataSource` and I don't want any database connection dependencies in unit tests.

Comment: Yes, this incures unneccessary setup in your case. And the @ DirtiesContext is also annoying it will slow your tests.

Comment: do note that when you migrate to Spring 4 that spring-mock 2.0.8 is obsolete and is assimilated into spring-test 4.x. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a `FactoryBean` to create the  `MyDao` (or any) mock to be injected into your `MyLogic` instance.

```
public class FactoryBeanForMocks<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {
    private Class<T> mockClass;

    public FactoryBeanForMocks(Class<T> mockClass) {
        super();
        this.mockClass = mockClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(mockClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return mockClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Make the factory bean entry into your `logicContext.xml` so that a mock of `MyDao` can be injected into `MyLogic`:

```
//logicContext.xml
<bean id="myLogic" class="com.MyLogic">
    <constructor-arg ref="myDao"/><!--or other type of injection--?
</bean>
<bean id="myDao" class="x.y.z.FactoryBeanForMocks">
        <constructor-arg name="mockClass" value="x.y.MyDao"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And this is your test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration("logicContext.xml")
public class BaseLogicTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyLogic myLogic;

    //You can inject the mock myDao into it so that you can stub/verify method calls on it
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Test
    public void testMyTestable() {
        //...
    when(myDao.process()).thenReturn("a");//stubbing myDao.process()
    assertEquals("a", myLogic.processRequest());// assuming myLogic.processRequest() calls myDao.process()
    }
}
```